# My VBA code .Range is not working as intended

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Column B9:B65 has a combobox in Sheet 1 that has values between A1 to K3 and L1 to W2 that a user can select from.
For example, the user can select values from A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,.....,K1,K2,K3,L1,L2,M1,M2,N1,N2,O1,O2,.......,V1,V2,W1 and W2.

Not necessary be in sequence. Can be in any order but will always be between A1 to W2.

The data for this is in Sheet 2 in Column B2:B56.

My requirement is to have 2 separate buttons to clear contents of column B in Sheet 1.

First button should clear values A1 to K3 from any where in column B9:B65 in sheet 1

Second button should clear values L1 to W2 from any where in column B9:B65 in sheet 1

For First button, I wrote the code below referring google, as I am new to VBA.

```
'Define variables that are to be used in the program
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws1LastRow As Long, ws2LastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim ws2Rng As Range
Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction: Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Dim strData As String

'Set ws1 and ws2 variable to the respective worksheets.
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)


'Assign values to ws1LastRow and ws2LastRow
ws1LastRow = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws2LastRow = 34  'Hardcoded as A1 to K3 is in between B2:B34

'To display values assigned to the variables use Debug.Print and get the results displayed in Immediate Window that gets populated using 'Ctrl+G'
Debug.Print ws1LastRow
Debug.Print ws2LastRow

'Set ws2Rng with the range from ws2 sheet that you want to compare
Set ws2Rng = ws2.Range("B2:B" & ws2LastRow)

For x = 9 To ws1LastRow
    
    On Error Resume Next 'To avoid 1004 error.
    
    ws1.Range("B" & x).value = wsf.VLookup(ws1.Range("B" & x).value, ws2Rng, 2, 0)
    
    
    'Used for Debugging
    'strData = Join(wsf.Transpose(ws2Rng.value), ",")
    'Debug.Print strData
    
    If (ws1.Range("B" & x).value = wsf.VLookup(ws1.Range("B" & x).value, ws2Rng, 2, False)) Then
                
    ws1.Range("B" & x).ClearContents ' I have to figure out a way to clearcontents of  row 'B & x : K & 
                                       x' with single line operation. 
      
     'Debug.Print x
    
    End If

Next x

End Sub
```

I want to clear content with single line such as `ws1.Range("B" & x : "K" & x).ClearContents` I am sure there is no such syntax but this is to give an idea of what I want to attain. Please suggest alternatives if any.

Debugging above code using **F8**, I found `ws1.Range("B" & x).value = wsf.VLookup(ws1.Range("B" & x).value, ws2Rng, 2, 0)` line **Vlookup** returns empty value so `ws1.Range("B" & x).value = empty`

I am stuck here and looking for a reason as to why my code doesn't work.

If there is more efficient way that meets the requirements, I will be more than happy to implement it. But at the same time I am curious to know the fault in this code.

Comment: Semi-colon needs to be in the quote as well `ws1.Range("B" & x  & ": K" & x)`

Comment: `ws1.Range("B" & x  & ": K" & x` worked fine. Thanks Davesexcel. However `ws1.Range("B" & x).value = wsf.VLookup(ws1.Range("B" & x).value, ws2Rng, 2, 0)` still returns empty value.